# How can I make chown permissions be permanent to files even after running the chown command?

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, file-permissions

I am running CentOS 6.

So I decided to take a more patient approach to building my server because I have had issues with it performing properly in the past.

So now, I am very very close to fixing all the issues I could never solve, but one of them is after I run the chown for a directory/s, it all works fine, but when I decide to create a file myself after that, it wont claim a owner, it will only do a group, which is changed to apache.

I hope that last part made sense.

The way I chowned it was apache:permissions

permissions being the group containing the users, and making apache the owner so it can write.

So when I make a new file now, it will clear apache off the owner, then remove the permissions group, and make it apache (48).

Should I just make the group the owner? I am unsure of a way to test to see if it matters at all, so input would be great.

Here is an example of the permissions, the 0:48 is AFTER I ran the chown command, the 48:500 is WHEN I ran the command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at setting the umask on the directory:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

That will ensure new files in the directory are created with the specified permissions/ownerships.

Your screenshot shows the root uid (0) for the new file - how are you creating that specific file?

Comment: Well, used Filezilla to create the file. Just a random one. I am using Vsftpd.

Comment: Ok, I now understand the tutorial. I decided to apply 'umask 007', and well, even when I create files through FTP, they show up as 0:48.

And when I create files through ssh, by doing 'touch filename', I am unable to see the file in filezilla. It's all being done under root, both on filezilla and ssh.

Comment: Ok well, just realized file permissions are completely different then owner/group permissions.. At least I think? http://puu.sh/a7TEb/d29bc3a812.png